# Mount /home to another disk in Azure VM

Tags: centos, azure

I have a CentOS 7.4 and I followed this guide to mount the new disk on my system.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/add-disk

At first I made a symbolic link but can't achieve what I want because /home already exists, how can I mount safely /home in the new disk without losing the current data?

My objective is to easily migrate this disk in the future to another VM, should I need to know anything else before mounting this disk in another VM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you already have the partition setup and working. What you need to do first is to copy the home dir from root partition to the new partition. Let's say its mounted on /mnt/disk1

1) Copy /Home (Replace variables accordingly)

```
sudo rsync -aXS --exclude='/*/.gvfs' /home/. /mnt/disk1/home/.
```

2) Find uuid of new partition

```
sudo blkid
```

3) Update fstab /home path

```
UUID=<UUID_from_blkid>   /home    <partition_type>          defaults       0       2
```

4) Move old home

```
cd / && sudo mv /home /old_home && sudo mkdir /home
```

5) Reboot

After that, you should have your home working as intended but located in a different partition.

Comment: Yes, I did these [steps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/add-disk#connect-to-the-linux-vm-to-mount-the-new-disk). 
I will try your solution tomorrow. By the way, care to explain the parameter -X of rsync command?

Comment: -X makes sure you are preserving extended attributes of the file system available in ext3, ext4, reFS, and many others such as ACLs, which is a more flexible permission mechanism. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes